# WinHttpException on azure app service

Tags: api, azure, azure-web-app-service, hosts

I have project that calls an API, and I needed to add a record in the hosts file of windows :

```
xx.xx.xx.xx    externalapi.something.com
```

But now I deployed the project in a azure app service and I receive the following error every time I try to call the API :

> WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved

I tried to add a **A** record in azure domain manager to map the IP address to the domain name but it does not solve the issue.

Is there a way to fix the problem ?

Comment: Is this an internal API or something that is hosted by someone (or some company) on the internet?  If it's public, curious that there is only an IP address...can you share the actual address?

Comment: It's an external API @BrendanGreen. But I'm not sure yet if I can share the IP address it's for a private company

Comment: Hosted by you, or a 3rd party?  Can you share the real URL?  If it's hosted by you, can you provide some additional details of how it's hosted, and what exactly the DNS setup for it's domain is.

Comment: it hosted by a 3rd party, actually I have no access or idea how the API is hosted, the company just give me the record to add in the hosts file in order to call there API : `40.119.10.125 upgrade.warime.com`